# Visible light excitation by heavy particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, laser, protons

Can I excite visible light from an atom by a proton or muon beam? How would that be possible?

Comment: Given that energetic particles can and do interact with electrons, this question seems poorly researched. In addition to @dmckees's answer below, and the existence of PIXE (particle induced x-Ray emission), please refine you question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows lack of research efforts.

Comment: I am aware of PIXE, but I was asking about light in the visible range excited by a heavy charged particle. I was confused if heavy particles will only interact with core hole electrons due to energy and mass, or they also interact with higher orbit electrons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is simply about making light in the visible range, then the answer is ***"that's what most [scintillators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scintillator) do"***. However, the amount of light generated by any given ionizing particle is very small, so they can not be seen by the unaided eye.<sup>1</sup>

Mind you, many modern plastic scintillators have so much fluor in them that they do glow visibly in sunlight (or sometimes even bright artificial lighting).

In any case, scintillation requires one of several sets of fairly special chemical properties to occur and is not a particularly common behavior.

---

<sup>1</sup> Geiger and Marsden viewed a chip of scintillator through a microscope in [the original Rutherford Scattering experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger%E2%80%93Marsden_experiment), so this is mostly a matter of the limiting sensitivity of the human eye.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from scintillation, which is explained in dmckee's answer, and the trivial cases, where the atom is excited by the collision and the radiates as it returns to the ground state (as happens in a Frank-Hertz tube, although the particles there are electrons not muons or protons), there is [Cherenkov radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation).

This kind of emission occurs if charged particles travel through a dielectric medium faster than the phase velocity of light in that medium and the radiation usually has visible components. (But it is a collective phenomenon, not emission of light by individual atoms).

As with scintillation it is used in certain kinds of particle detectors. One example are neutrino detectors such as [IceCube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IceCube) or [Super Kamiokande](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Kamiokande) which measure the Cherenkov radiation caused by the highly relativistic secondary particles with photomultipliers.

Another kind of detector using Cherenkov radiation are atmospheric Cherenkov telescopes, such as [H.E.S.S.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.E.S.S.), that typically are used to image particle showers generated by high energy cosmic radiation (such as high energy gamma particles). Here the atmosphere of the Earth itself acts as detection medium.